# Angularjs reset value to selected account value on switching

Tags: angularjs, html

I am new to AngularJS and I am trying to create a dynamic page calling same function and replacing value with new account json response.

Let's consider that I am having two accounts with same mail id.

If I login successfully all my account name (i.e. my profile name) will be displayed in a dropdown box.

The first account will be my default account and when i try to switch to another account then onclick of account name the page should be reset with new account details by clearing all the previous account details.

When I click on new account name it is not switching and when I refresh the page the new account values get replaced in some place where I gave array length = 0.

In some places where I did not define the size of an array the new account values getting added to old account values.

```
My displaynames = [
  {
    displayname: "KalaiManager - Shubiksha Apt",
    groupzcode: "MANSAR",
    profileurl: "http://prod1.groupz.in/GroupzMobileApp/ProfilePhoto/44984"session_id: "576b82dc4eabb0780e0b5a96"
  },
  {
    displayname: "KalaiManagerA - Anura Apt",
    groupzcode: "CRPLSAR",
    profileurl: "http://prod1.groupz.in/GroupzMobileApp/ProfilePhoto/45005"session_id: "576b82dc4eabb0780e0b5a98"
  }
]
```

My controller :

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app')

.controller('UserDataController', function($rootScope, $scope,$window,$http,$q, UserService, FlashService, $cookieStore) {
       $scope.model = { 
                'dropDownData':[],
                'birthdays':[]
                   };


    var displaynames = $rootScope.displayList; // displaynames is mentioned above and here i have set it as global in my code
    console.log($rootScope.displayList);  
    console.log(displaynames);
    console.log($rootScope.currentSession);


        $scope.model.dropDownData = [];
        $scope.model.selectedvalue = [];
        $scope.model.membername = [];
        $scope.model.countries = [];
        $scope.model.states = [];
        $scope.model.cities = [];
        $scope.model.segments = [];
        $scope.model.roles = [];
        $scope.model.birthdays = [];
        $scope.selectedcountry = [];
        $scope.selectedstate = [];
        $scope.selectedcity = [];
        $scope.selectedsegment = [];
        $scope.selectedrole = [];
        $scope.groupzlist = [];


        $scope.selectedcountry.length = 0;
        $scope.selectedstate.length = 0;
        $scope.selectedcity.length = 0;
        $scope.selectedrole.length = 0;
        $scope.model.selectedvalue.length = 0;
        $scope.model.membername.length = 0;

        console.log($scope.selectedcountry.length);

        $scope.initializeMethods = function(){

        $scope.getDisplayList = function(){

             console.log(displaynames);
             for(var i=0; i<displaynames.length; i++)
              { 
                $scope.model.dropDownData.push(displaynames[i].displayname); // we can itterate and set the drop down values

                console.log($scope.model.dropDownData);

            }

            $scope.model.selectedValue = displaynames[0].displayname;   // set model value

            console.log($scope.model.selectedValue);

             $window.localStorage.x = $scope.model.dropDownData;  
             //setting data in cookies

         }



        $scope.getselectval = function() {
            console.log($scope.model.selectedValue);

           if($scope.model.selectedValue != null){

            var selectedvalue = $scope.model.selectedValue;
            var currentAccount = selectedvalue.split(" - ");
            console.log(currentAccount);
            var selectedmembername = currentAccount[0];

            var selectedShortname = currentAccount[1];

            console.log("selectedmembername:"+selectedmembername+"***");

            for(var i=0; i<displaynames.length; i++){

               var displayedValues = displaynames[i].displayname;
               var accountName = displayedValues.split(" - ");
               var memberName = accountName[0];
               console.log(memberName);

               if (selectedmembername === memberName) {

                   var currentSession = displaynames[i].session_id;
                   console.log("currentSession : "+currentSession);

                   $scope.model.selectedvalue.push(currentSession);
                   $scope.groupzlist.push(displaynames[i].groupzcode);
                   console.log($scope.groupzlist);
                   console.log("selectedvalue : "+currentSession);
                   $scope.model.profileurl = displaynames[i].profileurl;

                   $cookieStore.put('currentSession', currentSession);
                   console.log(currentSession); 
               } 
            }
            $scope.getSessionInfo();
        }
        $window.localStorage.x = $scope.model.selectedvalue;              
    }

        $scope.membername = function() {

            console.log($rootScope.currentSession); 

            var json = {
                  "json": {
                    "request": {
                      "servicetype": "6",
                      "functiontype": "1000",
                      "session_id": $rootScope.currentSession
                    }
                  }
                }

            UserService.membername(json).then(function(response){
                if (response.json.response.statuscode == 0 && response.json.response.statusmessage =='Success'){

                    var memberName = response.json.response.user[0].membersdetails.membername;
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(memberName));
                    $scope.model.membername.push(memberName);
                }
            })
        }

        $scope.getSessionInfo = function(){

            console.log($rootScope.currentSession); 

            var json = {
                  "json": {
                    "request": {
                      "servicetype": "6",
                      "functiontype": "1000",
                      "session_id": $rootScope.currentSession
                    }
                  }
                }

            UserService.getSessionInfo(json).then(function(response){
                if (response.json.response.statuscode == 0 && response.json.response.statusmessage =='Success'){

                    var groupzdetails = response.json.response.user[0].groupzdetails;

                    console.log(JSON.stringify(groupzdetails));
                    var memberdetails = response.json.response.user[0].membersdetails;
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(memberdetails));


                    var checkNetworkAdmin = memberdetails.networkadmin;
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(checkNetworkAdmin));

                        $scope.Geography(checkNetworkAdmin);
                }
            })
        }


    $scope.Geography = function(data){

        console.log(data);
        console.log($rootScope.currentSession);

        if(data == 0){

            var json = {
                  "json": {
                    "request": {
                      "servicetype": "6",
                      "functiontype": "6002",
                      "session_id": $rootScope.currentSession
                    }
                  }
                }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(json));

            UserService.Geography(json).then(function(response){


                 if (response.json.response.statuscode == 0 && response.json.response.statusmessage =='Success'){
                     var geography = response.json.response.geography;
                     console.log("Geography : "+JSON.stringify(geography));      

                     for(var i=0; i<geography.length; i++){

                     $scope.model.countries.push( geography[i].countryname);
                     console.log($scope.model.countries);

                         if(($scope.model.countries != [])||($scope.model.countries != null)){

                         for(var j=0; j<$scope.model.countries.length; j++){
                            $scope.model.states.push(geography[i].states[i].statename);
                            console.log($scope.model.states);

                             if(($scope.model.states != [])||($scope.model.states != null)){
                             for(var k=0; k<$scope.model.states.length; k++){ $scope.model.cities.push(geography[i].states[i].cities[i].city);
                             console.log($scope.model.cities);

                                 if(($scope.model.cities != [])||($scope.model.cities != null)){

                              var segments = "_ALL";

                                $scope.model.segments.push(segments);
                                console.log($scope.model.segments);      
                              }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
        });
      }
    }


    $scope.GetCountry = function(){
        if($scope.model.selectedCountry != null){
           $scope.selectedcountry = []; $scope.selectedcountry.push($scope.model.selectedCountry);
            console.log($scope.selectedcountry);
            $scope.GetState();
        }  

    }


    $scope.GetState = function(){

        if($scope.model.selectedState != null){

            $scope.selectedstate = [];
            $scope.selectedstate.push($scope.model.selectedState);

            console.log($scope.selectedstate);
            $scope.GetCity();

        }

    }

    $scope.GetCity = function(){

        if($scope.model.selectedCity != null){

            $scope.selectedcity = [];
            $scope.selectedcity.push($scope.model.selectedCity);
            console.log($scope.selectedcity);
            if($scope.selectedcity != null){
            $scope.GeographyAccounts();
            $scope.Birthdays();
            }
        }
    }


    $scope.GeographyAccounts = function(){
        var json = {
                  "json": {
                    "request": {
                      "servicetype": "6",
                      "functiontype": "6003",
                      "groupzcode": $scope.groupzlist,
                      "country": $scope.selectedcountry,
                      "state": $scope.selectedstate,
                      "city": $scope.selectedcity,
                      "segment": $scope.model.segments,
                      "session_id": $rootScope.currentSession
                    }
                  }
                }
        console.log("GeographyAccounts request : "+JSON.stringify(json));



        UserService.GeographyAccounts(json).then(function(response){

            if (response.json.response.statuscode == 0 && response.json.response.statusmessage =='Success') {

               console.log(response); console.log(JSON.stringify(response.json.response));

               var roles = response.json.response.accounts[0].roles;

               for(var i=0; i<roles.length; i++){ 
                   $scope.model.roles.push(response.json.response.accounts[0].roles[i].role);
                }

                console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.model.roles));
            }

        });
    }

    $scope.GetRole = function(){

        if($scope.model.selectedRole != null){

            for(var i=0; i<1; i++) {
            $scope.selectedrole.push($scope.model.selectedRole);
            }
        }
        console.log($scope.selectedrole);
    }


    $scope.HeadCount = function(){

      console.log("headcount");

        $scope.showGraph = !$scope.showGraph;
        $scope.submitButton = true;

        var json = {
              "json": {
                "request": {
                  "servicetype": "6",
                  "functiontype": "6001",
                  "session_id": $rootScope.currentSession,
                  "country": $scope.selectedcountry,
                  "state": $scope.selectedstate,
                  "city": $scope.selectedcity,
                  "segment": $scope.model.segments,
                  "groupzlist": $scope.groupzlist,
                  "roles": $scope.selectedrole,
                  "user": true
                }
              }
            }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
        UserService.HeadCount(json).then(function(response){

            console.log(response);

            if (response.json.response.statuscode == 0 && response.json.response.statusmessage =='Success') {

               console.log(response); console.log(JSON.stringify(response.json.response));
            }
        })

        if($scope.showGraph){
            var json_response =  {

                      "data": [
                        {
                          "standard": "Ist",
                          "max_students": 20,
                          "available_students": 8
                        },
                        {
                          "standard": "IInd",
                          "max_students": 15,
                          "available_students": 10
                        },
                        {
                          "standard": "IIIrd",
                          "max_students": 50,
                          "available_students": 22
                        }
                      ]
                    };           
     $scope.available_students = [ ['Ist', 8,], ['IInd', 10], ['IIIrd', 22]];
     $scope.maximum_students = [['Ist', 15], ['IInd',15], ['IIIrd', 50]];
     $scope.ordinals = ['Ist', 'IInd', 'IIIrd'];
     console.log($scope.ordinals.length);
     $cookieStore.put('xaxisLength',$scope.ordinals.length);

    }
};

      $scope.Birthdays = function(data, index){

          var current_date = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
          var date_time = current_date + " 00:00:00";
          console.log(date_time);      
            var json = {
                 "json": {
                    "request": {
                        "servicetype": "6",
                        "functiontype": "6000",
                        "date":date_time,
                        "country": $scope.selectedcountry,
                        "state": $scope.selectedstate,
                        "city": $scope.selectedcity,
                        "segment": $scope.model.segments,      
                        "session_id": $rootScope.currentSession,
                        "groupzlist": $scope.groupzlist
                    }
                }
            }

            console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
           UserService.Birthdays(json).then(function(response){

                var show_birthdays = [];
                     if (response.json.response.statuscode != 0 && response.json.response.statusmessage !='Success') {
                         show_birthdays = response.json.response.statusmessage;
                         console.log("show_birthdays "+show_birthdays);
                         $scope.model.birthdays.push(show_birthdays);
                         console.log(show_birthdays);

                     }else {
                            console.log("Greeting response: "+response);
                         var resp = response;
                        show_birthdays = resp.json.response.greetings;
                        console.log(show_birthdays); 


                         for(var i=0; i<show_birthdays.length; i++){
                             console.log(show_birthdays.length);
                            console.log($scope.model.birthdays.length);
                             $scope.model.name =show_birthdays[i].name;
                            console.log($scope.model.name); 
                            $scope.model.shortname=show_birthdays[i].shortname;
                            console.log($scope.model.shortname); 
                            $scope.model.role=show_birthdays[i].role;
                            console.log($scope.model.role); 
                            $scope.model.division=show_birthdays[i].division;
                            console.log($scope.model.division); 
                            $scope.model.profileurl=show_birthdays[i].profileurl;
                            console.log($scope.model.profileurl);


                              var getbirthdays = {};


                             getbirthdays.name = $scope.model.name;
                             getbirthdays.shortname = $scope.model.shortname;
                             getbirthdays.role = $scope.model.role;
                             getbirthdays.division = $scope.model.division;
                             getbirthdays.profileurl = $scope.model.profileurl;
                             $scope.model.birthdays.push(getbirthdays);
                             console.log($scope.model.birthdays);
                         }

                          console.log($scope.model.birthdays);
                    }

                }); 
            }
            $window.localStorage.x = $scope.model.birthdays; 
            //setting data in cookies

            $scope.logout = function()
            {
                var json = {
                      "json": {
                        "request": {
                          "servicetype": "6",
                          "functiontype": "5001",
                          "session_id": $rootScope.sessionIds 
                        }
                      }
                    }

                console.log(json);
            }


            $scope.getDisplayList();
            $scope.getselectval();
            $scope.GetCountry();
            $scope.membername();

     }
  });
}) ();
```

My html :

```
        <div class="well well-lg col-xs-30 text-left" style="background-color: grey;" ng-show="true">

        <img class="imgsize" style="padding:1px" ng-src="{{model.profileurl}}"/><br>
            <a class="text-center" style="text-decoration:none; color:white;" href="#">Select account</a><br>
        <div class="form-group">
           <select class="form-control" ng-model="model.selectedValue" name="groupzname" ng-change="getselectval(model.selectedValue)">
               <option ng-repeat="item in model.dropDownData track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
                   </select></div>
                </div>


     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#/Dashboard"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span>Dashboard</a></li>
      <li class><a href="#/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Profile</a></li>
         <li><a href="#/Account"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Account</a></li>
         <li><a href="#/Dropbox"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></span>Dropbox</a></li>
         <li><a href="#/Checklist"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>Checklist</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/Report"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Report</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/Settings"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/Help"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>Help</a></li>
    </ul></div>            
    </div>
    </nav>

     <div class="text-center" ng-controller="UserDataController as ctrl" ng-cloak data-ng-init="initializeMethods()">  
    <div class="col-sm-10 text-left" style="background:white"> 
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-control" ng-model="model.membername" name="membername" style="border:none;"> {{model.membername[0]}}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav" style="height:850px;">
      <div class="well">
      <form class="form-row " role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-14" for="fName">Country*</label>
          <select class="form-control" ng-model="model.selectedCountry" name="country" ng-change="GetCountry(model.selectedCountry)"> 
               <option value="">_ALL</option>
               <option ng-repeat="item in model.countries track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
                   </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-20" for="fName">State*</label>
          <select class="form-control" ng-model="model.selectedState" name="state" ng-change="GetState(model.selectedState)" ng-disabled="!model.selectedCountry"> 
               <option value="">_ALL</option>
               <option ng-repeat="item in model.states track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
                   </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-20" for="fName">City*</label>
          <select class="form-control" ng-model="model.selectedCity" name="city" ng-change="GetCity(model.selectedCity)"  ng-disabled="!model.selectedState"> 
               <option value="">_ALL</option>
               <option ng-repeat="item in model.cities track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
                   </select>
          </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-20" for="fName">Center*</label>
                        <select class="form-control" ng-disabled="!model.selectedCountry">
                        <option selected>_ALL</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-20" for="fName">Role*</label>
          <select class="form-control" ng-model="model.selectedRole" name="city" ng-change="GetRole(model.selectedRole)"  ng-disabled="!model.selectedCity"> 
               <option value="">_ALL</option>
               <option ng-repeat="item in model.roles track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
                   </select>
          </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" href="#" ng-click="HeadCount()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-hide="submitButton" ng-disabled="!model.selectedRole">SUBMIT</button>
                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>  
    </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel panel-primary"> 
                <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#F8F8FF; text-decoration:none; color:black"><b>Chart</b></div>
                <div class="panel-body" ng-show="showGraph">
          <plot class="barchart" height="300" width="400" yaxis-label-text="'No. of Students'"
                          xaxis-label-text="'standards'" ymin="0" ymax="100" xodomain="ordinals" >
                        <bar-group  type="'grouped'" arrangement="'vertical'" style="opacity:100;">
                            <bars  data="available_students" position-function="'/0'" value-function="'/1'"
                                  fill="'red'"></bars>
                            <bars data="maximum_students" position-function="'/0'" value-function="'/1'" fill="'blue'" ></bars>
                        </bar-group></plot>
                </div>
          </div>
           </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-top:40px">
        <div class="panel panel-primary" >
      <div class="panel-heading"><img src="css/images/Birthday.png" />BIRTHDAYS TODAY</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
     <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in model.birthdays track by $index">
              <b ng-if="!item.profileurl && !item.name && !item.shortname && !item.role && !item.division">No Birthdays Today</b>

              <div ng-if ="item.profileurl"><img class="imgsize pull-left" style="padding-right:4px" src="{{item.profileurl}}"/></div>
              <p class="list-group-item-text tsize text-left " >{{item.name}}<br>
             {{item}}</p></li>
          </ul>
        </div> 
        </div>
     </div>       
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `$rootScope.displayList` defined? Can you please add this code to see how you're defining it? Also try to reduce the code in question to the relevant methods because it's lots of code for a simple function.

Comment: I am defining in seperate controller as below             var displayList = [];
                for(var i=0;i<user.length;i++){
                   var jsonData = {};
                    jsonData["groupzcode"] = user[i].groupzdetails.groupzcode;
                    jsonData["profileurl"] = user[i].profileurl;
                    jsonData["session_id"] = user[i].session_id;
                    jsonData["displayname"] = user[i].displayname;
                    displayList.push(jsonData);                    
                }
                $cookieStore.put('displayList', displayList); }